# I wrote a PowerShell script to send an emali alert when the windows service hungs or stopped

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script that sends an email alert when the service status is hung or stopped, but when I run the script in PowerShell as an admin mode the script still shows running but won't give any error or output, please help me to solve this issue.

I have tried in Windows 10 OS but no response from the script file.

````
#AUTHOR: Kevin Olson 
#DATE: 4/29/2011 

#Machine to be monitored 
$Computer = "IN-LINGARCR-1" 

#Create an array of all services running 
$GetService = get-service -ComputerName $Computer 

#Create a subset of the previous array for services you want to monitor 
$ServiceArray = "RemoteRegistry"

#Find any iWFM service that is stopped 
foreach ($Service in $GetService) 
{ 
 foreach ($srv in $ServiceArray) 
 { 
     if ($Service.name -eq $srv) 
     { 
         #check if a service is hung 
         if ($Service.status -eq "StopPending") 
         { 
         #email to notify if a service is down 
         Send-Mailmessage -to lckreddy456@gmail.com -Subject "$srv is hung on $Computer" -from lckreddy456@gmail.com -Body "The $srv service was found hung" -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com 
         $servicePID = (gwmi win32_Service | where { $_.Name -eq $srv}).ProcessID 
         Stop-Process $ServicePID 
         Start-Service -InputObject (get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name $srv) 
         } 
         # check if a service is stopped '
         elseif ($Service.status -eq "Stopped") 
         { 
         #email to notify if a service is dow
         Send-Mailmessage -to lckreddy456@gmail.com -Subject "$srv is stopped on $Computer" -from lckreddy456@gmail.com -Body "The $srv service was found stopped" -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com 
         #automatically restart the service. 
         Start-Service -InputObject (get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name $srv) 
         } 
     } 
 } 
}```

Powershell script needs to send an email alert when the service stops or hangs.

Thanks in Advance.
````

Comment: [1] do you get any errors from the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet? [2] does the `stop/start` of the service work? [3] if you add a `pause` at the end of the script, do you see any messages of any kind?

Comment: I didn't get any error from the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet? or `start/stop` of the service is working fine, even if i add `pause` nothing is happening.

When i run the script i just get the below lines in the ouput windows after that nothing happens
`PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\lingarcr\Desktop\Service Hung.ps1
Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

Comment: With the below script the service is getting started but email is not going i am getting the below error.

Comment: you need to add your CURRENT code and the error msgs you are getting to your Original Post. scattering info across multiple comments is not effective.

Comment: The above code is my current code for the error which i mentioned above.

Comment: um, er, where is the error message that you show in your comment from 1 hour ago?

Comment: Hi,

How can i make the text colored or bold which will send as a Email subject and body in the above script.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do this, this way?

Why not just use GPP for the monitor the services, let GPP settings take action on the services and send you an alert via script. Just curious and an idea to consider.

Try something like this...

```
#Services to Monitor
$ServiceToMon = 'MSSQLSERVER' #define service name here
$voicesrv="voiceserv" #define voice server here

#Email Params
$From = "alert@alert.com"
        $To = "support@domain.com"
        $SMTPServer = "smtp"
        $Body = "Start the Servicve if Found stopped $status "
        $Subject = " Service Status for  $($env:computername) "

#Start services that are stopped
Get-Service -computername $voicesrv $ServiceToMon  | 
where {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'}  | 
Start-Service $ServiceToMon
timeout /t 10

$status = get-service $ServiceToMon
send-mailmessage -from $from -to $to -subject $Subject -smtpserver $SMTPServer -body $Body
```

Or one of these pre built samples:

> Send an Email Message with Service Status Via PowerShell
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/19/send-an-email-message-with-service-status-via-powershel
>
> PowerShell- Monitor Group Of Services on 'N' Servers & Notify Stopped
>   Services
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Monitor-Notify-a5fe1538

Comment: I got the below error when i run the script which you provided
`Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'RemoteRegistry'. 
This operation might require other privileges.
At C:\Users\lingarcr\Desktop\Untitled4.ps1:13 char:1
+ Get-Service -computername $Service  |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperation 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerS 
   hell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
 `